# A tricky question involving inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I've tried to solve this but I don't seem to get anywhere.

The question states:

> Tom's home is $1800$ m from his school. One morning he walked part of the way to school and then ran the rest. If it took him $20$ mins or less to get to school, and he walks at $70$ m/min and runs at $210$ m/min, how far did he run?

My attempts to solve it got me stuck here:

> $$\frac{x}{70}+\frac{y}{210}≥\frac{1800}{20}$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the distance he walks be $x$ and the distance he runs be $y$ .

We know that $velocity= \frac{distance}{time}\implies time = \frac{distance}{velocity}$

So your equations comes to ;

$\frac x{70}+\frac{y}{210} \le 20 $

$\implies \frac{x}{70}+\frac{1800-x}{210}\le 20$$\quad $ since $y = 1800 -x$

$\implies 3x+1800-x\le4200$

$\implies 2x\le2400$

$\implies x\le 1200$

$\therefore y\ge600$

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
r = \mbox{distance covered while running}\\
w = \mbox{distance covered while walking}\\
s_r = \mbox{running speed}\\
s_w = \mbox{walking speed}\\
d= \mbox{total distance}\\
t=\mbox{estimated time to school}\\
\epsilon = \mbox{slack variable}
$$

we have

$$
d = w  + r \\
\frac{w}{s_w}+\frac{r}{s_r}=t + \epsilon^2
$$

Now solving for $w,r$ we have

$$
 w=\frac{s_r s_w t}{s_r-s_w}+\frac{s_r s_w \epsilon^2}{s_r-s_w}-\frac{d s_w}{s_r-s_w}\\
 r=  \frac{d s_r}{s_r-s_w}-\frac{s_r s_w \epsilon^2}{s_r-s_w}-\frac{s_r s_w t}{s_r-s_w}
$$

or

$$
w \le \frac{s_r s_w t-d s_w}{s_r-s_w} = 1200\\ 
r \ge \frac{s_r (d-s_w t)}{s_r-s_w} = 600
$$

NOTE

We have assumed that $s_r > s_w$